# ListView force re-inflate of list row layout after data changes

Tags: android, listview

I have the following code in my ListAdapter

```
    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View childView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        I dataItemForChild = null;
        if (childPosition >= dataModel.size())
        {
            // its an extra row
        }
        else
        {
            dataItemForChild = (I) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        }

        boolean isEvenRow = (childPosition % 2 == 0);
        if (childView == null)
        {
            final HashMap<Integer, View> viewMap = new HashMap<Integer, View>();
            childView = inflateChildView(isLastChild, isEvenRow, childPosition, groupPosition, dataItemForChild);
            childView.setTag(viewMap);
            addViewMappingCache(viewMap, childView);
            populateChildView(isLastChild, isEvenRow, childPosition, groupPosition, dataItemForChild, childView, viewMap);
        }
        else
        {
            populateChildView(isLastChild, isEvenRow, childPosition, groupPosition, dataItemForChild, childView, (HashMap<Integer, View>) childView.getTag());
        }
        return childView;
    }
```

The problem is I have varying layouts I use for different rows in my list. When I update the data and then call adapter.notifyDataChanged(), since the childView is not null, it won't call inflateChildView again and therefore the layout on some rows no longer matches the required ones for the data.

Is there a way to 'invalidate' a particular row or blow away its layout cache so the childView it passes in is null?

The specific use case I'm trying to implement is a special last row that says "Load More". Once more is loaded, I want that LoadMore row to be replaced with a data row and then (if there is any more) the new last row should be the LoadMore row.

Comment: when you change your data at that time call onCreate(savedInstanceState) method after doing this.

Comment: I don't want to re-create my whole view! Just force a particular row to fully reload complete with re-inflating the row layout.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using [getItemViewType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29). It's great when your list contains different kind of rows. Adapter implementation will manage caches for each kind of rows independently.

Comment: So do I assign a specific arbitrary integer to each row that has a different layout?

Comment: @MikeS Yes. E.g. you have 3 different kind of rows. You need to use integer 0, 1 and 2.

Comment: @MikeS hm, you're using 'ExpandableListAdapter', aren't your? It doesn't have `getItemViewType` at all. Sorry, I thought you're using usual `Adapter`.

Comment: Yeah I'm using the equivalent - public int getChildType(int groupPosition, int childPosition) with no success :(